# integrity constraint violated - parent key not found - OneToOne and ManyToOne

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

Facing issue inserting an entity into database. I am using Hibernate JPA.

I have tables Reminder and ReminderAction and Each Reminder will hold current status of ReminderAction (ie. OneToOne) and end of transaction each Reminder will have many ReminderActions (with different status).

```
DB Table columns are

REMINDER --> REMINDER_ID (PK), CURRENT_ACTION_ID (FK)...
REMINDER_ACTION --> REMINDER_ACTION_ID (PK), REMINDER_ID (FK)...


Reminder Entity
---------------------

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "REMINDER_SEQ_STORE")
@Column(name = "REMINDER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
public Integer getReminderId() {
return reminderId;
}



@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = ReminderAction.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "CURRENT_ACTION_ID")
public ReminderAction getCurrentAction() {
return currentAction;
}


ReminderAction Entity
---------------------

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="REMINDER_ACTION_SEQ_STORE")
@Column(name = "REMINDER_ACTION_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getReminderActionId() {
return reminderActionId;
}


@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,targetEntity=Reminder.class)
@JoinColumn(name="REMINDER_ID")
public Reminder getReminder() {
return reminder;
}


DAO
---

public void saveOrUpdate(final E transientObject) {
getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(transientObject);
getCurrentSession().flush();
}
```

During saveOrUpdate, hibernate gets the sequence for Reminder and ReminderAction from DB

```
Hibernate: select REMINDER_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select REMINDER_ACTION_SEQ.nextval from dual
```

But during flush(), **hibernate trying to insert ReminderAction first** and due to ReminderID in ReminderAction is null its throwing **ORA-02291: integrity constraint (REMINDER_ACTION_FK) violated - parent key not found**

Refered below threads and problem because of trigger in DB. **But I dont have any triggers for Reminder and Reminder_Action table in DB.**

1. [JPA Bidirectional One to Many Foreign Key Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715184/jpa-bidirectional-one-to-many-foreign-key-issues)
2. [Integrity constraint violated just when I commit the transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332930/integrity-constraint-violated-just-when-i-commit-the-transaction-solved)
3. [Hibernate: Insert issue - Parent Key not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052631/hibernate-insert-issue-parent-key-not-found)

**How can I ask hibernate to insert Reminder first then ReminderAction?**

**UPDATE:**

I tried by removing SequenceGenerator from Reminder and ReminderAction and manually set the IDs during saveOrUpdate and end up with same exception

```
Reminder rem = (Reminder)transientObject;
rem.getCurrentAction().setReminderId(5);
rem.getCurrentAction().setReminderActionId(5);
rem.setReminderId(5);

getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(transientObject);
getCurrentSession().flush();



Hibernate: insert into REMINDER_ACTION (REMINDER_ID, REMINDER_ACTION_ID) values (?, ?)
binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - 5
binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - 5
SQL Error: 2291, SQLState: 23000
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (REMINDER_ACTION_FK) violated - parent key not found
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am pulling your answer out of the question, and putting it into a dedicated answer:

Make ReminderAction in Reminder as nullable=true and Reminder in ReminderAction as nullable=false

```
Reminder Entity
---------------

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = ReminderAction.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "CURRENT_ACTION_ID", nullable=true)
public ReminderAction getCurrentAction() {
return currentAction;
}

ReminderAction Entity
---------------------
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,targetEntity=Reminder.class)
@JoinColumn(name="REMINDER_ID", nullable=false)
public Reminder getReminder() {
return reminder;
}
```

Doing this hibernate will insert Reminder first then ReminderAction. Thanks